# winsock - recv - Network Connection Issue

Tags: c++, networking, recv

In my C++ application I'm using the `recv` function in a loop.
I want to identify a network connection issue by getting a negative value from recv function.

The one thing I can see in my tests is that when I'm getting off the network cable, I can wait for ~minute till I can see that my application got this negative value.

Do you know what is the time duration for the C++ code to know that a network connection issue occur? Can I manage this time?

Comment: When you get a 'negative value' you also get an *errno,* which you should examine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no sane way of doing this on the TCP-only level. The option that was intended for this is [`SO_KEEPALIVE`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html), but it's pretty useless.

Implement application-level heartbeats and mark the socket disconnected when no data or heartbeat was received within specified time (this pretty much assumes non-blocking mode, or at least a [`select(2)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) loop with timeout).

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with C++ code. It has everything to do with the particular network protocol you are using. Assuming it's TCP, it's basically forever. An idle TCP connection has no packets associated with it and may never detect a connection loss.

If you want to detect the loss of a particular interface, use your platform's interface state monitoring functions.