# C++ Functions According to TCP

Tags: c++, networking, recv

I'm using recv function (C++) in order to get indication about network problem (it return negative value in this case)

Looking here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-100 at TCP Connection Failures, I see that there are R1 and R2.

R1 is when TCP informs application that there is a problem. R2 is when the connection is closed.

“The value of R1 SHOULD correspond to at least 3
retransmissions, at the current RTO.  The value of R2 SHOULD
correspond to at least 100 seconds.”

RTO (Retransmission Timeout) typically starts at 3 seconds, so for R1, it might be after about 10 seconds.

as far as I understand receive function will let me know about R2. Do you know about a way to get R1 in C++ application?

10x.

Comment: linux or windows ? recv is not a "C++ function", it comes from a networkink lib, most likely windows sockets or linux sockets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [winsock - recv - Network Connection Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231832/winsock-recv-network-connection-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On most systems, *recv()* transmit informations by two means : the *return code* and by setting the global variable *errno*.

To know what is returned/set in each case, you have to look at the exact API of the recv() function.

- R1 (problem) : *recv()* returns SOCKET_ERROR (windows) or -1 (linux), then you look at the value from *WSAGetLastError* (windows) or *errno* (linux) for details
- R2 (connexion closed) : I'm not sure, the API is unclear. Just try it out ;-)

Full doc :

- windows : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- linux : http://www.linux-kheops.com/doc/man/manfr/man-html-0.9/man2/recv.2.html