# TCP retransmission Timeout Detection in C++

Tags: c++, networking, tcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Functions According to TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244332/c-functions-according-to-tcp)

In my windows C++ application I'm using winsock API.

I want to detect network errors in my C++ functions.

Using wireshark I can see that after there is a network error there are TCP retransmission packets.

Do you know how can I detect TCP retransmission timeouts with C++ functions?

Comment: Just curious - but if you detected that a TCP retransmission has occurred, what would you do about it?  And given that it will retransmit to mitigate packet loss issues, why do you care?  In general, if the packet loss is so large that the connection can't get any bytes across, you'll just get an error or socket-close notification when calling send/recv.

Comment: that's a requirement - I need to know an indication for retrasmission timeout for doing a sequence of operations. regarding send/recv - in wireshark I can see that I get it for long time after the TCP retrasmission timeout occur.

Comment: @EJP - it is not a duplicate one. I want to know the indiccation for retrasmission timeout in C++. do you have an answer?

Comment: You could always use UDP and implement retransmission on your own.

Comment: It sure seems like a duplicate to me. Either you get an error from `send()` or TCP tells you nothing and keeps trying. You don't get to see under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no way. Sockets API just do not give you such low-level information. You can only detect total connection failure.

If you want EXACTLY what you asking for, you have to capture network packets and do flow analysis like in wireshark. Otherwise, please clarify why do you want to detect this. May be tcp keepalive or udp will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection is broken, all calls to `recv` (or `WSARecv`) will return an error. TCP itself have retransmission of packets built into the protocol, so you don't really have to do anything in most cases.

If the cable between the two peers is broken some way, then you won't get an error when receiving though. Then you have to implement your own timeout. If your higher-level protocol is using request-response (i.e. you send a request and the other peer returns a response) it is easy, if no response is received within X seconds, then close the connection and reconnect.

**Edit** In response to the comments:

TCP has this retransmission built-in, there is no way to turn it off, or get an error after the first timeout. One way to solve this is to use UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`) sockets instead. The problem with this is that you have to take care of everything yourself, including handling timeouts if there are no responses.

Comment: in wireshark I can see that recv function returs the error for more than a minute after TCP retrasmission timeout occur.

Comment: @gln The actual timeout may differ, but that's how TCP works. If a packet doesn't get a reply within a timeout then TCP transmits that package again, and if it still doesn't get a reply it propagates that error up in the network stack.

Comment: in wireshark I see 5 packets of TCp retrasmissin and then a lot of ARP packets that in the middle of them there I get the error with recv. I don;t want this. I want to know immediately after retrasimssion timeout.

Comment: @gln Then you should switch to UDP, which doesn't have this retransmission. It's part of TCP and can't be turned off. Of course, using UDP you won't get an error either, but you have to keep track of the timeout yourself.